# Why my reducer is called multiple times when I dispatch an action after importing store for feature?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I'm new to `ngrx` and I'm trying to have a state for each of my feature modules and also a state for app module. First, I registered `StoreModule` and it's effects in `app.module.ts` like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...,
    StoreModule.forRoot({app: fromApp.reducer}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([AppEffectsService])
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then I created a module called home with it's reducer and and effects service and used them like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...,
    HomeRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature(fromHome.homeFeatureKey, fromHome.reducer),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([HomeEffectsService]),
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

I put a `console.log` in my home reducer and saw every time I dispatch an action, I see the log twice per action! I don't now why my reducer is called twice per dispatch. And even when I add store to more modules, I see the repeated logs more.

The reducer looks like this:

```
const homeReducer = createReducer(
    initialHomeState,
    on(HomeActions.loadOrderTypesSuccess, (state, { orderTypes }) => ({ ...state, orderTypes })),
);

export function reducer(state: HomeState | undefined, action: Action) {
    console.log(action.type);
    return homeReducer(state, action);
}
```

And this is my effect:

```
  loadOrderTypes$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(HomeActions.loadOrderTypes),
    mergeMap(() => from(this.dataService.getOrderTypes())
      .pipe(
        map(orderTypes => HomeActions.loadOrderTypesSuccess({ orderTypes })),
        catchError(error => of(HomeActions.loadOrderTypesFailure({ error }))),
      )
    )
  ));
```

The creation of actions:

```
export const loadOrderTypes = createAction(
    '[Home Page] Load order type start'
);

export const loadOrderTypesSuccess = createAction(
    '[Home Page] Load order type success',
    props<{ orderTypes: OrderType[] }>()
);

export const loadOrderTypesFailure = createAction(
    '[Home Page] Load order type failure',
    props<{ error: any }>()
);
```

After dispatching the action, the log is:

```
@ngrx/store/init
15:23:36.470 app.reducer.ts:22 @ngrx/effects/init
15:23:36.505 core.js:38781 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
15:23:36.608 app.reducer.ts:22 @ngrx/store/update-reducers
15:23:36.609 home.reducer.ts:35 @ngrx/store/update-reducers
15:23:36.644 app.reducer.ts:22 [Home Page] Load order type start
15:23:36.644 home.reducer.ts:35 [Home Page] Load order type start
15:23:36.761 client:52 [WDS] Live Reloading enabled.
15:23:37.743 app.reducer.ts:22 [Home Page] Load order type success
15:23:37.744 home.reducer.ts:35 [Home Page] Load order type success
```

I want my reducer to be called once. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you also have effects associated with your actions?

Comment: usually when you dispatch one action, there would be a second action to represent success of the initial action.
have you installed Redux devtools yet? it helps a lot to understand how the actions behave

Comment: No I did not install it.

Comment: do you mind sharing in your question the part of your reducer where you placed the console.log ?

Comment: Yes I have effects associated with actions. but for example there is an action with type: `load data`. And when I dispatch the action I see the `load data` log twice.

Comment: I updated the question an added the reducer and my console.log statement

Comment: I got curious and change it on a reducer of one of my apps to see what happens there. The action is only called once in my app, so I believe there is something on your app causing it.
is the action you are dispatching also intercepted by an effect?

Comment: if it might be helpful I get `@ngrx/store/update-reducers` log twice too! And I am using lazy loading with preloading all modules

Comment: I updated the question so you can see my effect.

Comment: do you mind also sharing the creation of the actions?

Comment: Could you please also add the `loadOrderTypesSuccess` and `loadOrderTypesFailure` actions to the question?

Comment: just to be clear, what are the exact messages you get on you console.log once you dispatch `loadOrderTypes`?

Comment: I added the logs to the question

Comment: I don't know why the app reducer is called too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An action is dispatched to all reducers, this is by design.

We can't know which reducers to call because it's perfectly fine to modify state based on an action from another module.

Answer (score 0):

I was upgrading effects to v8 ngrx, and what called my issue, was in effects.

When deleted it `@Effect()`, the problem was solved.

Bad:

```
@Effect()
test$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(...
```

Good:

```
test$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(...
```